# How can I get the leading space of a large title in a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit

I am trying to align my table view with the large title in the navigation bar. I want to get the leading space for the title and set it as my table view's leading space. How can I get the leading space?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Standard value for the leading constraint for your TableView to align it with LargeTitles.[image: Here is the image for setting leading constraint as StandardValue.]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. However, I can not select standard value. Also is there any way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Have you implemented table view programmatically? If yes, then also you can add Standard value or you can add 20 pixels statically as standard value is 20 pixels.

Comment: Okay, I think 20 pixels is okay for iphone 6s plus. However, it is not aligned in iPhone SE 2nd edition. That's why I was looking a way to get leading space.